# How to get @UseAdviceWith working in Camel 3

Tags: java, testing, apache-camel, apache-camel-3

I am about writing some unit tests for production Camel routes in a Spring Boot application. To do so I use `adviceWith` technique and do not want the `CamelContext` to start before the advising is done. With Camel 2.24.2 my test class looks like a snippet below, I have ommited the details like autowiring and test expectations for brevity.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@UseAdviceWith
public class CamelApplicationTests {
    ...
    context.getRouteDefinition("test.simple").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("file:/home/outfolder")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .to("mock:outFolder");
            }
        });
    context.start();
    ...
}
```

Running this test I get logs as expected

```
INFO  melSpringBootExecutionListener - @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) before: class org.sample.CamelApplicationTests.testSimple
INFO  melSpringBootExecutionListener - Initialized CamelSpringBootRunner now ready to start CamelContext
INFO  spring.CamelAnnotationsHandler - Skipping starting CamelContext(s) as UseAdviceWith annotation was found and isUseAdviceWith is set to true.
```

Now, it's time for a migration towards Camel 3 and the advising part have to be rewritten as follows and it works just fine

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@UseAdviceWith
public class CamelApplicationTests {
    ...
    AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(context, "test.simple", route ->
        route.interceptSendToEndpoint("file:/home/outfolder")
            .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
            .to("mock:outFolder"));
    context.start();
    ...
}
```

Except that CamelContext is getting start automatically, so we have the advised route restarted

```
INFO  o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: test.simple started and consuming from: file:///home/infolder
INFO  o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
INFO  o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.4.3 (camel) started in 0.923 seconds
INFO  org.sample.CamelApplicationTests         : Started  in 11.544 seconds (JVM running for 13.935)
INFO  o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 45 seconds)
...
INFO  o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Route: test.simple is stopped, was consuming from: file:///home/infolder
INFO  o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Route: test.simple is shutdown and removed, was consuming from file:///home/infolder
INFO  org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier    : AdviceWith route after: ...
...
INFO  o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: test.simple started and consuming from: file:///home/infolder
```

It seems to be a bug, or am I missing something?

P.S.
After some researching I found [an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11955) have been fixed in Camel 2.21 version, so I have checked the `CamelSpringBootExecutionListener.java` file from `3.4.x` branch and it looks OK, but after taking a closer look at my logfile I noticed there was no *@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class) preparing* log, which means the `prepareTestInstance` method was never invoked, but I guess it should

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by migrating to Junit 5, now I have my test classes annotated like

```
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.CamelSpringBootTest;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.junit5.UseAdviceWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest
@UseAdviceWith
public class CamelApplicationTests {
    ...
}
```